# mysql_query() returns error unknown column '...' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

So I this script below

`$query = "SELECT CUST_ID FROM PINS ORDER BY CUST_ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);`

and I am receiving the error Unknown column 'CUST_ID' in 'field list'.

**The script can see the host, username, password, and database.**

This is the structure of my table

PINS
   Key: PIN_ID

```
    CUST_ID int(10)

    USR_ID int(10)

    PIN varchar(45)
```

This is what is in that table

```
'0', '1', '1', 'yu32b45sc4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b'

'1', '1', '2', 'yu32b45s202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70'

'2', '2', '1', 'yu32b45sc81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c'

'3', '3', '1', 'yu32b45seccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3'

'4', '4', '1', 'yu32b45sa87ff679a2f3e71d9181a67b7542122c'

'5', '5', '1', 'yu32b45se4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5'

'6', '6', '1', 'yu32b45s1679091c5a880faf6fb5e6087eb1b2dc'

'7', '1', '3', 'yu32b45se10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'

'8', '2', '2', 'yu32b45sc33367701511b4f6020ec61ded352059'
```

Please help!

Comment: On Linux column names are case sensitive. Did you verify that you are using the proper case in your queries?

Comment: "This is the structure of my table" Don't write down what you *think* it should be, use your tool to dump the current schema and post *that*.

Comment: I really like the fact that the example data features 4 columns while the table definition describes only 3...

Answer (score 0):

Is your table called PINS or pins? Probably this will work

```
SELECT CUST_ID FROM pins ORDER BY CUST_ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

You should know that the table and column names are case sensitive.

Comment: The fact that all colums and table names are uppercase is annoying me, bad design when you know that good SQL is all lowercase identifiers and uppercase keywords..

Comment: Which is what I did. If his column names are uppercase I can't change them. True story

Answer (score 0):

Please run the query

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Right before or after that query of yours and print out each row of the result. I wouldn't be suprised that you are not in the correct database although you think you are...